# Which sql will be faster and why?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a `student` table contains `id`, `class`, `school_id` having 1000 records.

There are 3 schools and 12 classes.

Which of these 2 queries would be faster(if there is a difference)

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE school = 2 and class = 5;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE class = 5 and school = 2;
```

Note: I just changed the places of the 2 conditions in `WHERE`.

Then which will be faster and Is the following true?

->probable number of records in query1 is 333

->probable number of records in query2 is 80.

Comment: why are number of records different and what indexes do you have?

Comment: The two statements are identical and should never return a different number of rows.

Comment: Less guessing, more profiling

Comment: are you sure? when you only switch the where conditions the result of the fetch records must be the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## hypothetical; to teach a DB concept

**"How your DB uses *cardinality* to optiize your queries"**

So, it's *basically* true that they are identical, but I will mention one thought hinting at the "*why*" which will actually introduce a good RDBMS concept.

Let's just say **hypothetically** that your RDBMS used the WHERE clauses **strictly** in the order you specified them.

In that case, the optimal query would be the one in which the column with **maximum cardinality** was specified first. What that means is that specifying `class=5` first would be faster, as it *more quickly* eliminates rows from consideration, meaning if the row's "class" column does not contain 5 (which is statistically more likely than it's "school" column not containing 2), then it doesn't even need to evaluate the "school" column.

Coming back to reality, however, you should know that almost *all* modern relational database management systems do what is called "building a query plan" and "compiling the query". This involves, among other things, evaluating the cardinality of columns specified in the WHERE clause (and what indexes are available, etc). So essentially, it is probably true to say they are *identical*, and the number of results will be, too.

Answer (score 6):

It seriously doesn't matter one little bit. 1000 records is a truly tiny database table and, if there's a difference at all, you need to upgrade from such a brain-dead DBMS.

A decent DBMS would have already collected the stats from tables (or the DBA would have done it as part of periodic tuning) and the order of the `where` clauses would be irrelevant.

The execution engine would choose the one which reduced the cardinality (ie, reduced the candidate group of rows) the fastest. That means that (assuming classes and schools are roughly equally distributed) the `class = 5` filter would happen first, no matter the order in the `select` statement.

Explaining the cardinality issue in a little more depth, for a roughly evenly distributed spread of those 1000 records, there would be 333 for each school and 83 for each class.

What a DBMS would do would be to filter first on what gives you the smallest result set. So it would tend to prefer using the class filter. That would immediately drop the candidate list of rows to about 83. Then, it's a simple matter of tossing out those which have a school other than 2.

In both cases, you end up with the same *eventual* row set but the initial filter is often faster since it can use an index to only select desired rows. The second filter, on the other hand, most likely goes through those rows in a less efficient manner so the quicker you can reduce the number of rows, the better.

If you *really* want to know, you need to *measure* rather than guess. That's one of the primary responsibilities of a DBA, tuning the database for optimal execution of queries.

Answer (score 5):

These 2 queries are strictly the same :)

Comment: did u run the query and noted the exact time it took?

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows affected will not and may not change simply because you reorder the conditions in the "where clause" of the sql-statement.
The execution time will also not be affected since the sql-server will look for a matching index first.

Answer (score -2):

First query executes faster than 2nd query because in where clause it filters school first so it is easier to get the class details later

Comment: modern DBs don't filter records two times, they do query compiling and run it in one go